# spring cloud config with github backend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I am struggling to fix this issue.
I am trying to use the spring cloud-config with github repo but it not fetching any config.
The server is working fine with file-based configuration but not working with GIT.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: false
      server:
          git:
            uri: https://github.com/${GIT_USER}/config-server
            searchPaths: organizationservice,personservice,zuulservice
            username: ${GIT_USER}
            password: ${GIT_PASS}
            skipSslValidation: true
            cloneOnStart: true
```

Boot and cloud version

```
    springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    springCloudVersion= "Greenwich.SR2"
```

Comment: "not working" isn't very helpful. Are there any logs or errors? You have `native` profile active which should be removed for git.

Comment: Thanks, mate. profile was the issue. There was no error in the logs

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591088/org-eclipse-jgit-api-errors-invalidremoteexception-invalid-remote-origin-spr?